# Sets that contain $2$ or $1$ different elements can we make them vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sets that contain $2$ or $1$ different elements can we make them vector spaces?

Answer is for $1$ element $yes$ for $2$ element $no$.

I know definition of vector space and it's $8$ axioms but don't know how use them to prove. Will be glad if you can help me.

Comment: $\Bbb F_2$ is a vector space over $\Bbb F_2$

Answer (score 1):

In general, a vector space over an infinite field $F$ can have

- $1$ element, if it's the trivial space,
- infinitely many elements.

However, a vector space over a finite field $F$ can have

- $|F|^k$ elements, if it's $k$-dimensional ($k=0,1,2,\ldots$),
- infinitely many elements.

This should answer your question.

---

*Edit.* I realized you may not be familiar with the idea of a dimension. In that case, you can just think of the product $F \times F \times \ldots \times F$ with coordinatewise operations on its elements.